# Email td in Outlook not rendering any padding or font settings at all

Tags: html-table, outlook, html-email

I'm at wits end trying to figure out why Microsoft Outlook on the desktop will not render any of the

tag settings or  tag for the "letter-text" td.

The text is showing up with no margins, no padding, and no specific font-sizing. I know this is related to not nesting correctly in tables but I cannot figure it out after staring at it forever. Any help is appreciated. I removed the hrefs for the two images for confidentiality.

Here is my style css:

```
  <style type="text/css">
      table {
        border-spacing: 0;
      }
      td {
        padding: 0;
      }
      p {
        font-size: 15px;
      }
      img {
        border: 0;
        border-width: 0;
      }
      a {
        color: #277fd2;
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      .first-text {
        border-top: 20px solid #ffffff;
        border-right: 30px solid #ffffff;
        border-left: 30px solid #ffffff;
      }

      .second-text {
        border-right: 30px solid #ffffff;
        border-left: 30px solid #ffffff;
        border-bottom: 15px solid #ffffff;
```

Here is the section of code:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <table
      align="left"
      role="presentation"
      width="100%"
      style="text-align: left; width: 100%; border-spacing: 0"
    >
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="side-images" align="left">
            <img
              src="REALHREFINREALLIFE"
              width="55"
              style="max-width: 55px; width: 100%; display: block; margin: 0"
            />
          </td>

          <td
            class="letter-text first-text"
            style="width: 81.67%; background-color: #ffffff"
          >
            <p
              style="
                margin: 0;
                font-size: 12.6px;
                font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                line-height: 18px;
                padding-bottom: 8px;
              "
            >
              Dear {{Recipient.PreferredFirstName__c}}{{#if
              Recipient.PreferredFirstName__c}}{{else}}{{Recipient.FirstName}}{{/if}},
            </p>

            <p
              style="
                margin: 0;
                font-size: 12.6px;
                line-height: 18px;
                font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                padding-bottom: 8px;
              "
            >
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste
              exercitationem sint fugit, atum ratione ea laboriosam sed!
            </p>

            <p
              style="
                margin: 0;
                font-size: 12.6px;
                line-height: 18px;
                padding-bottom: 8px;
              "
            >
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste
              exercitationem sint fugit, atum ratione ea laboriosam sed!
            </p>
          </td>
          <td class="side-images">
            <img
              src="SIDEIMAGE (real href in real life)"
              width="55"
              style="max-width: 55px; width: 100%; display: block"
            />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I have tried changing the padding to "border" and tried playing around with different table nesting no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inline the CSS.

So instead of this: `<td class="letter-text first-text" style="width: 81.67%; background-color: #ffffff">`

Write this:

```
<td style="padding:20px 30px 0 30px; width: 81.67%; background-color: #ffffff">
```

Font-size looks right, so not sure what's going on there. Perhaps the extra spacing is weirding your system out? I would have each HTML tag, with its styles, on the one line.